# How to reference loop index i in teradata SP?

Tags: teradata

Table2 has structureas
v_1, v_2, v_3

each time I only want to select one variable so want to reference loop index i in a stored procedure. Is this possible in TD?

++++++++++++++++++++++

```
replace procedure abc();
begin;
    declare i integer default 0;
    loopi: loop
    set i = i + 1;
        if i > 10 then leave loopi;
        end if;
        insert into table1 
        select * from table2
        where v_i = 1;
    end loop loopi;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to work as-is when you remove the semicolons after the REPLACE and BEGIN:

```
replace procedure abc()
begin
    declare i integer default 0;
    loopi: loop
    set i = i + 1;
        if i > 10 then leave loopi;
        end if;
        insert into table1 
        select * from table2
        where v_i = 1;
    end loop loopi;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Just tried, not working.
Error: column v_i not found in table2.
Seemes that loop index i is not solved.
Any advice?

Comment: Should `v_i` be `v_1` based on the table layout in your question?

Comment: It's your table, you should know about your columns :-)  I can't spot the loop variable in your select-statement, there's only "v_i = 1". You need to put a colon in front of the varaiable: ":i = 1"

Comment: sorry I didn't make it clear.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I want to write a loop. 

In the 1st loop, I want to select all the rows in the table with variable v_1 = 1.

In the 2nd loop, I want to select all the rows with variable v_2 = 1.

I have 10 variables for instance, so I want i = 1 to 10. And in the 10th loop, I want all the rows with v_10 = 1.

In the SP loop, how to solve for loop index i in the variable name: I've tried 'v_:i = 1'. Seems not working. TD still solves it as variable name v_:1 and gives an error saying column v_:i is not found in the table.

Please help here, thanks